# Salesforce LWC Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(ViewModel)' of undefined

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am getting this error when running a Salesforce scratch org application;

```
aura_proddebug.js:274 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(ViewModel)' of undefined
at getInternalField (aura_proddebug.js:274)
at Object.update (aura_proddebug.js:1793)
at updateCustomElmDefaultHook (aura_proddebug.js:5627)
at Object.update (aura_proddebug.js:5779)
at patchVnode (aura_proddebug.js:5021)
at updateStaticChildren (aura_proddebug.js:5000)
at aura_proddebug.js:5542
at runWithBoundaryProtection (aura_proddebug.js:8255)
at updateChildrenHook (aura_proddebug.js:5541)
at Object.update (aura_proddebug.js:5751)
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Right place for this question should be salesforce.stackexchange.com - There's a similar question in there: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262389/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-symbolviewmodel-of-und

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @GrafiCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to spot the issue.

This error has been thrown before in my org when I either didn't have the .html file or I had it with an improper spelling somehow; include case sensitivity on the names.

See related [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262389/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-symbolviewmodel-of-und):